# Best way to override child styles in styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a Component and I want to override it's styles. I have used styled-components to build them.

My doubt is, how can one override styles of a child component.

I want to know better approach.

Example

```
 const Child = styles.div'
      font-size: '10px'
    '
    const Wrapper = styles.div'
      color: red
    '
const DummyComponent = () => (
  <Wrapper>
    <Child>Hello</Child>
  </Wrapper>
)
```

I want to change padding or margin or any other property of child.

What is the better approach.
Using inline style or className. Or is there any better approach in styled-component to do this.

Using inline style

```
const DummyComponent = ({childStyles}) => (
  <Wrapper>
    <Child style={{...childStyles}}>Hello</Child>
  </Wrapper>
)
```

Using className

```
const DummyComponent = ({childClass}) => (
   <Wrapper>
       <Child className={childClass}>Hello</Child>
    </Wrapper>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use classNames to override the behaviors. you just need your rules stronger. tex:

```
const DummyComponent = ({childClass}) => (
   <Wrapper className="div--wrapper">
       <Child className="div--child">Hello</Child>
    </Wrapper>
)
// css
.div--wrapper .div--child{
  // override css go here
}
```

Comment: What is the disadvantage of using style over className

Comment: it is very difficult to override if you share the components in multiple places :). It is always easier to override that by adding css rules in separate files. And you have your choice to change the appearance by updating css files

Answer (score -1):

The CSS `!important` rule will override tags with higher precedence. For example, if you apply a class to the child element with the following code `background-color: green !important;` this will override other `background-color` rules that may be applied to the child element. This is the best way to override styles.

Comment: In general you would want to look at the style in devtools to find out what targeting is being used to apply a style and then write more specific targeting to override that if needed. You can use !important; however down the line if you want further overrides then you will have to use !important again while also making a more specific target anyway.